# Search files for regex and return which files contain matches

Tags: linux, search, regex, grep

I searched everywhere but didn't find out how to return a file content that matches given words or a regex.

```
cat /tmp/*.txt | grep "strings"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you just mean to `grep` the file(s) instead of [(uselessly) `cat`ing it/them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) to `grep`?

```
grep strings /tmp/*.txt
```

What `cat` does is that it combines all `*.txt` files into one big "file". If you `cat` multiple files, `grep` therefore will only see one input without a real name—it's all your files combined, fed through the pipe. This won't get you the file names, since you basically made everything one big file.

If you only want `grep` to return the files that match, use the `-l` option:

```
grep -l strings /tmp/*.txt
```

Comment: If you want to search for string_s_ (more than one), separate them either by `\|` (without the `-E` option) or by `|` (with the `-E` option), that is `grep 'foo\|bar'` or `grep -E 'foo|bar'`.

Comment: **ack** is an alternative tool that is great for this sort of thing